# Determine what object/table a saved query pertains to? (via an automation script)

Tags: maximo

In Maximo 7.6.1.1, I have saved queries that pertain to:

- Assets (ex. SIDEWALKS_ZONE1)
- Locations (ex. CITY_PROPERTIES)
- Other (ex. APPR_TREE_WO)

Is there a way to determine what the underlying object/table is for a given saved query via an automation script?

Answer (score 2):

The primary key on `QUERY` is `APP, OWNER, CLAUSENAME`. `APP` is a foreign key from `MAXAPPS`, where you can find the `MAINTBNAME` / main table of the application. The Saved Query is against the main table of the application.

More generally, you can use the Same As Object and Same As Attribute properties of attributes in DB Config to go and find where the values they hold come from. Of course, there are exceptions, but the rule holds well enough to be among your first exploratory stops.